# Regex over a html page

Tags: regex, html-parsing

Hello I'm trying to select 4 values from a html page (static page of a printer) The thing is i have some issues succeeding. I have  some attempts all fail could you guys help me pls:

hole page = http://pastebin.com/e7eKAV0x

code of intresst:

```
               <tr>                        
                 <td>                      
                   Yellow Cartridge
                   <br>
                   Order 305A (CE412A)
                 </td>
                 <td class="alignRight valignTop">  
                         40%
                       †
                 </td>
               </tr>
```

(Please use inspect / check the page) I need the 40% value from 4 different filds(printer colors). When color is  out  `--`

My last try:

```
public void buildCartigesAndValue(String ipString) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Starting mining over IP " + ipString);
        String context = getUrlSource(ipString);
        System.out.println(context); 

        urlPart = "/info_colorUsageJobLog.html?tab=Status&menu=ColorUsageLog";
        if (context.contains("HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn") || context.contains("HP Color LaserJet CM2320nf MFP")) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "PRINTER TYPE ======= HP Color LaserJet CP2025dn");
            regexColorContent = "\\w+\\W{1}Cartridge (?<!Printer)";
            regexTagContent = "(<td{1}>)([^<]{1}[^.{20}][^&nbsp;&nbsp;].*?)(</td>)";
        }
        else if (context.contains("HP LaserJet 400 color M451dw")){
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "PRINTER TYPE ======= HP LaserJet 400 color M451dw");
            regexColorContent = "\\w+\\W{1}Cartridge (?<!Printer)";
            regexTagContent = "Cartridge.{50}";
        }

        List<Integer> vals = findCartegisProcentr(context);
        List<String> colors = findCartigesColor(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.size(); i++) {
            if (colors.get(i).contains("Printer")) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(colors.get(i));
            addNewColorVal(colors.get(i), vals.get(i));
        }
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Stopping sucessfully ---- MAP ---- " + this.colorAmountMap.toString());
    }


public List<Integer> findCartegisProcentr(String context) {
    List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList<>();

    regexValContent = "\\d{2}|-{2}"; // FOR PARTICULAR THE VALUES

    Pattern patternTagContent = Pattern.compile(regexTagContent);
    Matcher matcherTagContent = patternTagContent.matcher(context);

    Pattern patternValContent = Pattern.compile(regexValContent);
    while (matcherTagContent.find()) {
        Matcher matcherValContent = patternValContent
                .matcher(matcherTagContent.group());
        matcherValContent.find();
        try {
            vals.add(Integer.parseInt(matcherValContent.group()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            vals.add(0);
        }
    }
    return vals;
}
```

Comment: Using `{1}` is useless, you should know that. `[^&nbsp;&nbsp;]` doesn't make sense since it's in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Also using `(?<!Printer)` at the end of an expression is useless in this case since `(?<!a)b` is to check if `b` is not preceded by `a` so it's like saying `abc(?!<d)` check if there there is no `d` instead of `c`. That said, why don't you use a robust html-parser ?

Comment: i am restrected from hmtl prasers, and dom does not work because of an firewall... and the first models set works :), the last one is pain...

Comment: [Something](http://regex101.com/r/xA4gQ4) really quick. You might then loop again through the results to parse further. Take care.